# Images are not displayed at run-time in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

The images are displayed in the XAML but when I run the program the images aren't displayed in the list boxes. It just shows the boxes but without the images.

here is the code:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="103,156,67.6,65">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Image Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="225" Source="pictures/gw1.jpg"></Image>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Image Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="225" Source="pictures/ja2.jpg"></Image>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Image Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="225" Source="pictures/tj3.jpg"></Image>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What's the exact path of that file in your project and the exact path of your images?

Comment: The post says the following: Change the build action to 'Resource'. Also your pack url is wrong. Either use:

Source="pack://application:,,,/Resource/UserCost2013Open16.png"
or simply

Source="/Resource/UserCost2013Open16.png"                                                    But i can't find anything about build action, where is it located?